# Extending Vectors to Invertible Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and suppose $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in\mathbb{F}^n$ and $b=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)\in\mathbb{F}^n$ are such that $\sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k=1$. Is it always possible to find $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ such that the first row of $A$ is $a$, the first column of $B$ is $b$, and $AB=I$?

To me the answer is clearly yes but I am having some trouble proving this. I am fairly certain it is not needed but $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed.

For those wondering what the context is for this problem, I am trying to determine whether two subalgebras are conjugate and I can construct an inner automorphism provided this fact always holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is always possible. It should be straightforward that with the given information, we can always complete $(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$ to a full-rank matrix $A$ with $A b = \hat{e}_1$ (where $\hat{e}_1$ is the first column of the identity, and is often referred to as the first standard basis vector). Indeed, we just need to find $n - 1$ vectors $\{v_2, \cdots, v_n\}$ that are linearly independent in the space $b^\perp = \{x: x^T b = 0\}$ to serve as the remaining $n - 1$ rows. This will always be possible as $\dim(b^\perp) = n - 1$. Since $a^T b = 1 \neq 0$, it will follow that $\{a, v_2, \cdots, v_n\}$ is linearly independent (why).

From here, we just need to choose the columns $b_i$ of $B$ so that $A b_i = \hat{e}_i$. As $A$ is invertible, this equation always has a solution.